# Kafka streams interactive queries - how to wait for streams to process all current records from input topic before querying state store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to write a kafka streams application which do some transformations and put the data into a materialized key value store and then I read it from the store (I need to query compacted data). One important thing is that instead of starting the streams app and exposing a rest endpoint, I would like to:
`start application -> process all data from topics to the data store -> query the store -> exit application (all in a sequential way)`.

The problem I am facing is that after starting the KafkaStreams (listener on the RUNNING state) I see no way to wait for data to be processed from input topics to the store.
If I start querying the store directly after KafkaStreams state is RUNNING (and I do it in separate thread) I am reading empty store and application exits before any data being actually read.

I have found a promising method: **allLocalStorePartitionLags()** - but after restarting application (with kafka-streams-application-reset) and calling *cleanup()* before *start()*, I am getting all zeros (*currentOffsetPosition, endOffsetPosition, offsetLag* are all zero). Maybe they are lags for the internal topics?
To sum up:

**How can I wait for the store to be in sync with input topic before querying it?** (and additionally: **what is the allLocalStorePartitionLags() method behavior?**)

EDIT:

I have already data coming to multiple kafka topics (and used for different scenarios) and I need to get the most current values for all keys twice a day. I can do it with typical interactive queries scenario: keep kafka streams application running continuously to keep the stores updated and query it only twice a day - that works.
But for my needs (relatively small traffic) running the application for limited time (just to update store with what came to topics in the meantime, run queries and exit) would be much cheaper.
As noted by Hamed, streams have no end, so what I would like to achieve is to **make sure that store have been updated with all events up to specified timestamp (or to specified offset), before querying it**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Apache Kafka is an open-source distributed event streaming platform.

So you have to model your application to process events in streams. There is not an end in streams. If you can't model and think like this, **YOU ARE USING THE WRONG TOOL**.

Comment: Of course there is always such a chance that I am using wrong tool, but currently I am convinced that I am not :)
I have already data coming to multiple kafka topics (and it is already  used for different scenarios). I am aware that streams have no end. This question is about Kafka Streams  and its SDK and not kafka in general.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Since nothing is impossible by programming, I would suggest two ways to do so

1. define a consumer to get all messages from the topic with their offset as `current offset`. So, you have `start offsets` of partition when you are starting your process and `current offset` calculated before processing the data. Just process the data until `offset` is less than `current offset`. Note that offsets are defined per partition.
2. Use unlimited time windows that have a start time. and limited the result for current or any specific time.

   ```
   source.groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(UnlimitedWindows.of().startOn(Instant.ofEpochMilli( System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000)))
            .count() // **process your data here**
            .suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofDays(1), Suppressed.BufferConfig.maxRecords(100000)))
            .toStream();
   ```

the example above defined a window from exactly 24 hours ago to infinite. then by suppress you filter the final result to 1 day from the start point which is when you started to process.

I have not tested the second way, but this is a solution that comes to my mind.